# How can I create a 'floating' and 'displacement' effect? Using React, CSS3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, animation, frontend

I'm hoping to build out a simple landing page that is a little bit different. Here's a mockup I've quickly put together:

[image]

It's pretty simple:

- A large text heading in the middle (say, the name of the website / business)
- Surrounded by lots of elements, SVG images of varying size (In the mockup, represented by coloured rectangles and circles).

The first effect I'd like to add that sets this website apart is that the elements "float" they slowly move in random directions.

If they collide with each other, they change direction, such that they do not overlap.

Finally, the mouse/cursor/point has a similar displacement effect when hovering over elements.

Here is my attempt at capturing this behaviour in a gif:

[image: 'Floating' and 'Displacement' behaviour captured in a gif]

**I've never embarked to build something quite like this before, is there a javascript library best suited to help me achieve something like this?**

In my own research I've found [TwoJS](https://two.js.org/) who's [particle sandbox demo](https://two.js.org/examples/particle-sandbox.html) seems to showcase somewhat of the functionality I'm looking to build.

Comment: perhaps a large `canvas` spanning the background would be better for this sort of thing?

Comment: you should use a canvas. each element should be a class that inherits from a base one.. the base class should handle the animations. heres an example of a canvas rendering elements and also has collision detection :) http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/n6U8D/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and example. I've seen canvas a lot, but admittedly have never used it. I'll look into it and report back in ;-)